# Applying Lambda to Recode (tricky) Strings to Numbers

Tags: string, list, python-3.x, lambda

I have a large data set of NFL scenarios, but for the sake of illustration, let me just reduce it to a list of 2 observations. Like this:

```
data = [[scenario1],[scenario2]]
```

Here is what the data set consists of:

```
data[0][0]
>>"It is second down and 3. The ball is on your opponent's 5 yardline. There is 3 seconds left in the fourth quarter. You are down by 3 points."

data[1][0]
>>"It is first down and 10. The ball is on your 20 yardline. There is 7 minutes left in the third quarter. You are down by 10 points."
```

I can't build any models with the data in string format like this. So I want to recode these scenarios into new columns (or features if you will) as quantitative values. I thought I should first get the data frame squared away:

```
down = 0
yards = 0
yardline = 0
seconds = 0
quarter = 0
points = 0

data = [[scenario1, down, yards, yardline, seconds, quarter, points], [scenario2, yards, yardline, seconds, quarter, points]]
```

Now is the tricky part, some how I have to populate the new columns from the information from the scenario column. Tricky, because for instance, in the 2nd sentence if the word "opponent's" is present, that means we must calculate it as 100- whatever the yardline number is. In the above `scenario1` variable, it should be 100-5=95.

At first I thought I should just separate all the numbers and throw away the words, but as pointed out above, some words are actually necessary to correctly assign the quantitative value. I have never made a lambda with this much subtlety. Or perhaps, a lambda is not the right way to go? I'm open to any/all suggestions.

For reinforcement, here is what I want to see (from `scenario1` if I entered:

```
data[0][1:]
>>2,3,95,3,4,-3
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lambda is not the way you're gonna want to go here. Python's `re` module is your friend :)

```
from re import search

def getScenarioData(scenario):
    data = []

    ordinals_to_nums = {'first':1, 'second':2, 'third':3, 'fourth':4}
    numerals_to_nums = {
        'zero':0, 'one':1, 'two':2, 'three':3, 'four':4,
        'five':5, 'six':6, 'seven':7, 'eight':8, 'nine':9
    }

    # Downs
    match = search('(first|second|third|fourth) down and', scenario)
    if match:
        raw_downs = match.group(1)
        downs = ordinals_to_nums[raw_downs]
        data.append(downs)

    # Yards
    match = search('down and (\S+)\.', scenario)
    if match:
        raw_yards = match.group(1)
        data.append(int(raw_yards))

    # Yardline
    match = search("(oponent's)? (\S+) yardline", scenario)
    if match:
        raw_yardline = match.groups()
        yardline = 100-int(raw_yardline[1]) if raw_yardline[0] else int(raw_yardline[1])
        data.append(yardline)

    # Seconds
    match = search('(\S+) (seconds|minutes) left', scenario)
    if match:
        raw_secs = match.groups()
        multiplier = 1 if raw_secs[1] == 'seconds' else 60
        data.append(int(raw_secs[0]) * multiplier)

    # Quarter
    match = search('(\S+) quarter', scenario)
    if match:
        raw_quarter = match.group(1)
        quarter = ordinals_to_nums[raw_quarter]
        data.append(quarter)

    # Points
    match = search('(up|down) by (\S+) points', scenario)
    if match:
        raw_points = match.groups()
        if raw_points:
            polarity = 1 if raw_points[0] == 'up' else -1
            points = int(raw_points[1]) * polarity
        else:
            points = 0
        data.append(points)

    return data
```

Personally, I find storing your data like `[[scenario, <scenario_data>], ...]` is a bit odd, but to add the data to each scenario:

```
for s in data:
    s.extend(getScenarioData(s[0]))
```

I would suggest using a list of dictionaries because using indexes like `data[0][3]` could get confusing a month or two from now:

```
def getScenarioData(scenario):
    # instead of data = []
    data = {'scenario':scenario}

    # instead of data.append(downs)
    data['downs'] = downs

    ...

scenarios = ['...', '...']
data = [getScenarioData(s) for s in scenarios]
```

EDIT: When you want to get a value from the dicts, use the `get` method to prevent raising a `KeyError` because `get` defaults to `None` if the key is not found:

```
for s in data:
    print(s.get('quarter'))
```

Comment: Wow, that's super helpful!! I will try different data frames and see which pans out better. I'm starting to see it your way with a list of dicts.

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Comment: I'm sure it works, but I got the error "NoneType" object has no attribute: group. After looking through the data, I noticed some scenarios are really simple, like "You are down by 3. What do you do?"  Should I use `try`/`except` for this? or is there some other way to default to 0 or na? I noticed some of your recodes have `if`, perhaps I should tag that on all the recodes?

Comment: I wasn't sure how strict the syntax the scenarios was, so I left it pretty open to errors. I will edit the answer to account for no match found in each `search` call

Comment: great, now I see the power of `search`. Also thanks for the `get` tip, it works perfectly now. You the man!

Comment: Happy to help :)